# Register Laravel Service Providers In A Loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to add functionality to enable plugins in an app. To do this I would like to register a Service Provider for a PluginManager class that will scan a */Plugin* directory for plugins that have been 'installed' (i.e. dragged and dropped in there) by an end user. I don't want the end user to have to manually add the Service Providers for each plugin to the standard providers array etc.

I would like each of these installed plugins to have their own Service Providers. So, **is it possible to register these Service Providers *dynamically* in a loop from the PluginManager's Service Provider** that will be added to the standard providers array? Possibly using the *App::register()* method?

This is psuedo-code, but I was thinking something along the lines of:

*PluginManagerServiceProvider.php*

```
<?php namespace Plugins;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class PluginManagerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

   public function register()
   {
       $this->app->singleton('PluginManager', function($app)
       {
           return new PluginManager();
       });

       $pluginManager = $this->app->make('PluginManager');

       // Register other plugin Service Providers in a loop here?
       foreach ($pluginManager->getInstalledPlugins() as $plugin)
       {
           $this->app->register($plugin->getServiceProviderPath);
       }

   }

}
```

What do you think? Am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Comment: for what it's worth, I personally don't see any issue with what you are doing. A quick test I just did on a 4.2 install shows that adding the plugin service provider to `app/config/app.php` and registering other service providers inside of that one does in fact fire the dynamically registered plugin providers, so there shouldn't be any issue for you in doing it this way.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try using:

```
App::register('FooServiceProvider');
```

? That should do the trick if your providers are autoloaded. If they are not you'd most likely have to manually autoload them then call above on every of them.

Comment: This is covered in the manual entry [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc) for 4.2 under the heading _Registering A Service Provider At Run-Time_

Comment: @MaksymCierzniak That's what I'm suggesting in the loop above but using _$this->app->register($plugin->getServiceProviderPath);_ instead of the App facade as $this->app is already available. My question is, is it OK to load additional service providers in this way from a single service provider's (in this case the PluginManagerServiceProvider) register method?

Comment: Also, is it OK to instantiate the PluginManager class within it's Service Provider (**e.g.** where I have `$pluginManager = $this->app->make('PluginManager');`?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be ? :) If this is what you need then just go for it, service providers are not expensive to use, their purpose is to just register some bindings and stuff so you definitely shouldn't have any problems with this solution. And about the second question, yes, it is definitely right to load the PluginManager from provider, after all this should be the purpose of this service provider you created ;)

Comment: @MaksymCierzniak Thanks for the info. I've not used Service Providers before so I just didn't want to start off on the wrong path and have to refactor everything further down the line.